# X710-AT2 10G network problems on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I bought myself an ASROCK E3C256D4U-2L2T mobo with an Intel X710-AT2 network card hoping to get a 10G network connection. Unfortunately, I can't get the network card working under Ubuntu 22.04. It was working on Fedora 38 liveCD (kernel 6.2), which I ran for testing.

I am wondering if any of you have a working card under ubuntu. The card is seen by the system, has an UP status, but does not get an address from the DHCP server. I have tried:

- different kernels (5.15.0-76-generic, 5.19.0-1028-lowlatency, 6.1.0-1015-oem)
- compile the driver from Intel's website (i40e-2.22.20)
- update NVM

```
Num Description Ver.(hex) DevId S:B Status
=== ================================== ============ ===== ====== ==============
01) Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X710 9.32(9.20) 15FF 00:002 Up to date
    for 10GBASE-T
```

- The card operates unstable when connected to the 1G port. Error from mikrotik: `DMZ_DHCP offering lease 192.168.20.250 for 9C:6B without success.` Sometimes it gets an IP address, but there are problems with communication.
- It seems that the card has problems with TX packets. The router counts few or none of them.
- I have changed cables but they are cat 5e. I will still check cat 8. Cable is short, ~2m, so it is rather not it. Tested for continuously.

First of all, I would like to confirm that this card works for someone. I myself don't know if this is an OS problem or some specific network configuration problem, but the fact that everything seems to work under fedora tends to make me suspect ubuntu - not sure which part tho.

Comment: I noticed that ethtool -S has rx_dropped, so I started looking into this. I found someone recommending disabling all power saving settings in the bios. Also, the Intel® Ethernet 700 Series Linux Performance Tuning Guide says that increasing the rx_dropped counters may suggest a buffering problem. So I started experimenting with:

```
ethtool -G eth12 rx 256 tx 256
ethtool -C ethX adaptive-rx off adaptive-tx off rx-usecs 0 tx-usecs 0
```

Some mixture of the above caused packets to pass through my Mikrotik. Setting same stuff after reboot didn't make it work.

Comment: There is also a [report to Intel](https://community.intel.com/t5/Ethernet-Products/X710-AT2-onboard-not-working-on-Ubuntu-22-04-Debian/td-p/1514284) about this.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another person owning Asrock E3C256D4U-2L2T having exact same issues with 10G interface + problem with throughput of PCI devices (PCI-Express bandwidth available for this device may be insufficient for optimal performance). I think that there is some problem with MOBO design and it's overall functionality. I bought ASUS P12R-E-10G-2T as I was sick and tired of of going back and forth with it Asrock and it's issue. ASUS P12R-E-10G-2T has exact same NIC integrated and it works out of the box without any problems on Ubuntu 22.04. I contacted Asrock via supplier and they also confirmed problems with NIC on their mobo. I'll be returning my Asrock as it's clearly broken and who knows if this is not the same for the whole batch or series of this mobo.